# Accessing child class property

Tags: c#, linq, class, inheritance

I have 2 classes which are inherited in this manner

```
public class PartsParent
{

}
public class PartsCar : PartsParent
{   
    public int WheelRadius { get; set; }       
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class PartsBike : PartsParent
{

    public int Length { get; set; }       
    public int Weight { get; set; }       
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

And i have a function that accepts the class PartsParent as parameter and how can i convert this as partsCar / as PartsBike inside the function and access properties like   Price WheelRadius etc?

```
private int PriceCollection(PartsParent mainObject)
{

  int _price=0;
  mainObject.OfType(PartsCar).Price;// something similar?? 
  return _price;
}
```

Comment: `((PartsCar)mainObject).WheelRadius` should be worked. However, if you must cast an object to a child type, you should try to re-design it.

Comment: BTW, you should define `Price` in the `PartsParent` since all of your child types need a price. If so, you can access the `mainObject.Price` without convert it.

Comment: @J.C Yes you are right that common properties should be a part of Parent class only and  the object properties in question is a sample  only. Your suggestion solved my issue

Comment: Sure, this code should work. However, I suggest you consider redesign your program. Like @AymenDaoudi's answer, casting an object to child type doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are trying to cast a parent type to a child type, that is not really possible, why ?

The answer is that the parent P you are trying to cast to child C1 can be actually and originally of type C2, so the cast would be invalid.

The best way to explain this is a phrase that I read somewhere here on stackoverflow

> You can't cast a mammal into a dog - it might be a cat.
>
> You can't cast a food into a sandwich - it might be a cheeseburger.

What you can do though to turn around this situation is something like this :

```
(mainObject is PartsCar) ? (PartsCar)mainObject : mainObject
```

Which is equivalent to :

```
mainObject as PartsCar
```

Then access mainObject's cast result using the [null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) (because if as fails, the cast result will be null instead of throwing an Exception).

The generic method [`OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) that you tried to use is an extension method that can be used with objects of type `IEnumerable<T'>` , which I guess is not your case.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of inheritance is to group up what is common in a super class, and leave other specific details to sub-classes. So if a property, say `Price`, is excepted from all sub-classes, then it should be declared in the super class.

However, if you still want to use it this way, then what are you looking for is:

```
int _price = ((PartsCar)mainObject).Price;
```

However, what if the object was of some other class, say `PartsGift` that inherits from `PartsParent`, but does not have a price? Then it will crash.

You almost really need to check your design.

BTW, if you want to check if an object is really of a specific class, then you can use is.

```
int number = 1;
object numberObject = number;
bool isValid = numberObject is int; // true
isValid = numberObject is string; // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is` keyword to check the type and `as` keyword to convert to the target child type as following.

```
 if (mainObject is PartsCar)
 {
     var partscar = mainObject as PartsCar;
     // Do logic related to car parts
 }
 else if (mainObject is PartsBike)
 {
     var partsbike = mainObject as PartsBike;
     // Do logic related to bike parts.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you separate uncommon properties your code into block:

```
if (mainObject is PartsCar)
{
    //Seprated code for PartsCar
    // WheelRadius...
    //Price...
}
else if (mainObject.GetType() == typeof(PartsBike))
{
    //Seprated code for PartsBike 
    //Length
    //Weight
    //Price
}
```